# Operation type [updateNetworkInterface] failed with message "IP 'X.X.X.X' is already being used by another resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

i have created a subnet in vpc network with subnet 192.168.0.248/29 ip in this subnet has not been used for any purpose but when i set static ip 192.168.0.254 error "This IP address is either in use by another resource or is reserved for another use" i checked the list of IPs but this IP is not used anywhere. Does anyone know why this error occurs?

I checked the IP configuration, read google cloud document. I hope there is an explanation as to why this error occurs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The subnet 192.168.0.248/29 consists of addresses from 192.168.0.248 to 192.168.0.255 inclusive. 192.168.0.254 is the second to last IP address.

**The second-to-last address is reserved by Google Cloud for potential future use.**

Every subnet has four reserved IP addresses in its primary IP range.

[Reserved IP addresses in IPv4 subnets](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/subnets#reserved_ip_addresses_in_every_subnet)

Comment: Here is the answer. thank you. it turns out I misread the documentation I only read in vpc network and Reserve a static internal IP address